# Hover on JQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, css

What I aim is that if when hovered, and if the cell is already active, the hovered **TD** will be black (for deactivation), and orange for if it's still inactive (for activation).

But with my code, every time I hover it on td, the color won't return on its previous background color. (Still orange or black even the mouse leaves) What event should I be using?

```
$("td").hover(function(){
    var cell = $(this).html();

    if(cell == "")
        $(this).css( "background-color", "orange");
    else
        $(this).css( "background-color", "black");
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the condition cell == "". It's better to check .length to see if there's something or not because checking == "" will not work if it's null for instance. Also, try to use .mouseover() instead of .hover()

Comment: Any reason not to use `:hover` and forget the JS?

Comment: The hover method is made to use the mouseenter event with the mouseleave event, this function takes 2 parameters, the in (mouse enter) and the out (mouse leave).
You should change the state of your element in each of these events.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the empty value it's better to check the length of the content

```
$("td").hover(function(){
    var cell = $(this).html();

    if(cell.length===0)
        $(this).css( "background-color", "orange");
    else
        $(this).css( "background-color", "black");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hover uses a handler in and handler out.
2 functions separated by comma
[hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

I would use classes for the highlighting

```
.orange {
background: none no-repeat 0 0 orange;
}
.black{
background: none no-repeat 0 0 black;
}
```

Then use addClass and removeClass

```
$("td").hover(
    function(){
        var cell = $(this).html();
        if(cell == "") {
            $(this).addClass("orange");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("black");
        }
    },
    function () {
            $(this).removeClass("orange").removeClass("black");
    }
});
```

Comment: May i optimise your code? : `$("td").hover(function(){
    var cell = $(this).html();
    $(this).toggleClass( cell=="" ? "orange" : "black");
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating and toggling a class, this will help you return to default state.

```
<Style>
.active {background-color:black;}
.inactive {background-color:orange;}
</style>

<script>
$("td").hover(function(){
var cell = $(this).html();

if(cell == ""){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
}
else{
     $(this).toggleClass("inactive");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` instead of `hover()`.

Answer (score 0):

`.hover()` is a great function for toggling, but in you case, you are better by spliting the mouse leave and enter :

```
$('td').on({
    mouseenter : function(){
        var cell = $(this).html();

        if(cell.length===0)
            $(this).css( "background-color", "orange");
        else
            $(this).css( "background-color", "black");
    },
    mouseleave : function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', '');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is when you call `$(this).css( "background-color", "orange");` or similar you are changing the CSS and it'll stay that way until you ask to change it again.

When you only pass `hover` a single argument, it runs that same argument when you both enter, and leave, however if you pass a second argument in, then the first will be called for enter, the second for leave.

```
$("td").hover(function(){
    //Put original code here
}, function(){
    $(this).css( "background-color", /* Whatever the original color was */);
});
```